# Why doesn't SuperGenPass work on some sites when I use Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, bookmarklet, password-generation

Bookmarklet SuperGenPass sometime fails to popup when I click the bookmark in Chrome.  It does however work when on the same page in Firefox; an example is http://www.engadget.com/login

This behaviour also replicated on a new Chrome tab (understandably, there is no domain), but some sites just fail to launch it meaning you have to go to another site, open it up, enter in [something] to get the 'Regenerate password' link, enter the domain manually then finally enter your master password to get the generated password!

Something about the makeup of the page seems to make SuperGenPass think that it isn't able/required to popup.

The FAQ doesn't make any mention of this fact, neither does a quick Google turn up anything that looks relevant.

Does anyone else have the same issue?  How can it be fixed?

I'm on Windows using the current release of Chrome (5.x at the moment, but probably 18.x by the time you read this next week based on Google's seemingly logarithmic release numbering).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [SuperGenPass patched for Google Chrome](http://nexus.zteo.com/blog/2009/11/30/supergenpass-patched-for-google-chrome/) :

> Unfortunately, in Google Chrome,
>   SuperGenPass chokes on some pages. 
> I
>   do not blame Chrome for that: it’s for
>   security reasons.
>
> I’ve patched the basic version of
>   SuperGenPass so that it can now work
>   on those pages. I am not sure that it
>   fixes everything for everybody but I
>   hope it makes your life easier, like
>   it does mine.
>
> Just [go to this page](http://www.voilaweb.com/tools/sgpchrome.html) and get the
>   patched bookmark.
>
> If you are using a customized
>   bookmark, I am afraid that you will
>   have to patch it yourself. 
> Here is
>   what the patch looks like:
>
> Look for
>
> ```
> var%20FrameTest=window.frames[i].src;
> ```
>
> Replace with
>
> ```
> var%20FrameTest=window.frames[i].src;var%20FrameTest=window.frames[i].src;FrameTest=window.frames[i].document.forms;
> ```

Comment: Brilliant, cheers!  Well worth the 50 bounty :)

Comment: I updated the page linked in harrymc's reply to provide a solution for Chromium users who find that bookmarks are now being "re-escaped" and as a consequence simply drag/dropping the bookmarklet stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great, but sadly the author of SuperGenPass doesn't seem to have updated the project, for at least 2.5 months of writing, despite having this bug fix posted on his forum.

I hope someone else can restart the SuperGenPass project?

There is the idea of working on making a new version of SuperGenPass to fix the bugs and generally improve it. That is something you or other people (who have the time + skills) could do. In fact I had the same idea myself, as I wrote on their forum: http://discuss.supergenpass.com/SuperGenPass-development-f1175681.html